# TYPO3 extbase - query with multiple languages - how to define language for subtables / persistance\ObjectStorage

Tags: typo3, extbase

I have a table with multiple 1:n subtables that have translations.

Now the client wants to list all records on all language versions of the website. The problem is that Extbase caches the values of the different ObjectStorages and does not differentiate between the languages. Now if I have two records with the same record the first one will fetch the title and this one is then being used for all records. So I have a crazy language mis-match.

I would like to define the language overlay of the subtables fixed for sys_language_uid and don't know how. This code: https://gist.github.com/hhoechtl/a374f7526440ba987c19 does work perfectly for a single-select but it does not work for my listview..

Is there any way I could force the language of the subqueries?

As an example. This is an italian record (sys_l = 1) and it gets shown on the german detailview with german subinfo: (https://jobfinder.look4u.it/de/job?tx_jobfinder_stellenanzeigen%5Baction%5D=show&tx_jobfinder_stellenanzeigen%5Bcontroller%5D=Stellenanzeigen&tx_jobfinder_stellenanzeigen%5Bstellenausschreibung%5D=149&cHash=6da4a876cac6125e3b0f5b0924f35463)

When you open it on the italian page ( https://jobfinder.look4u.it/it/job?tx_jobfinder_stellenanzeigen%5Baction%5D=show&tx_jobfinder_stellenanzeigen%5Bcontroller%5D=Stellenanzeigen&tx_jobfinder_stellenanzeigen%5Bstellenausschreibung%5D=149&cHash=6da4a876cac6125e3b0f5b0924f35463 ) the additional info is nicely in italian thanks to the code from hhoechtl above.

But the problem is in the listview where german (0) and italian gets mixed: https://jobfinder.look4u.it/de/anzeigen-arbeitgeber/agenturen

Extbase takes the values of 2 properties from the first record (sales controller) in italian and then keeps that lookup for all folowing records. And I'm not able to change the lookup here in the listview. The code from hhoechtl somehow doesnt work in this query.

Comment: Which TYPO3 version? How do you store the records? Are they created in the BE forms or in any other way?

Comment: This site is running on v10. It's a normal Extbase Extension. I create the records via frontend via extbase so everything get's linked up nicely. 

I added two examples.

Comment: Normally Extbase runs with different languages. In the case you're creating them in Frontend I'd think that the creation in the action is done wrong or the TCA has a configuration issue.

Comment: It does run with languages. And it works fine it connects the italian subtables to the italian entry. But I want to change which language of subtable to display. Thats the problem..

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution. The patch released in July 2022 actually solves exactly this problem!

https://review.typo3.org/c/Packages/TYPO3.CMS/+/75099/2

Since I'm running v10 on this site I have manually implemented the patch on my T3 version and now Extbase is behaving as it should.